# C++ program compiles in Visual Studio 2010 but not Mingw

Tags: c++, constructor, casting, operator-overloading, template-classes

The program below compiles in VS 2010, but not in a recent version of Mingw. Mingw gives me the error "conversion from int to non-scalar type 'tempClass(it)' requested". Class "it" is just a simple class to use in the template for the purpose of illustration.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
class tempClass{
    public:
    T theVar;

    tempClass(){}

    tempClass(T a){
        theVar = a;
    }

/*  tempClass <T> & operator = (T a){
            (*this) = tempClass(a);
            return *this;
    }
*/
};

class it{
    public:

    int n;

    it(){}

    it(int a){
        n = a;
    }
};

int main(){
    tempClass <it> thisOne = 5;         // in MinGW gives error "conversion from int to non-scalar type 'tempClass(it)' requested"
    cout << thisOne.theVar.n << endl;   // in VS 2010 outputs 5 as expected
}
```

Commenting in/out the assignment operator portion doesn't seem to make a difference - I didn't expect it to, I just included it because I also hope to do things like `tempClass <it> a = 5; a = 6;`, in case this is relevant to the answer.

My question is, how can I get this syntax to work as desired?

Comment: Unrelated, but why are you using tools that are a decade old? A lot has happened in the past 10 years, both with the C++ standard and with your tools standards compliance.

Comment: MinGW is largely obsolete considering the [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/about) provides a much, much better experience. It has modern compilers as well. A 10 year old C++ compiler is effectively junk.

Comment: I just had a computer with a C++ compiler already installed from a while back. I only installed Mingw because I wanted to use variadic templates. Either way, how can I get this syntax to work?

Comment: @tadman the raison d'etre for MinGW and derivatives is to use gcc to build code that uses the Windows API ,  so it is not obsoleted by WSL

Comment: @M.M If you prefer that to Visual Studio then knock yourself out I guess. I see a lot of people struggling with MinGW and they're just trying to compile, period, no particular target in mind.

Comment: @tadman someone who can't install a compiler is probably not the target audience for this discussion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MinGW is correct to refuse the code since it relies on *two* implicit user-defined conversions. One from `int` to `it` and one from `it` to `tempClass<it>`. Only one user-defined implicit conversion is allowed.

The below works since it only requires one implicit conversion:

```
tempClass<it> thisOne = it(5);
```

You can also let the constructor do the conversion which will let you do
`tempClass<it> thisOne = 5;`. In the below example the constructor will accept *any* argument and will try to initialize `theVar` with it. If `U` is convertible to `T`, it'll compile and work as expected. Otherwise you'll get a compilation error about an invalid conversion.

```
template<class T>
class tempClass {
public:
    template<typename U>
    tempClass(U a) : theVar(a) {}

//private:
    T theVar;
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/E9xech)

Comment: I guess I didn't post the actual question, which is, how can I get that syntax to work?

Comment: @HumidMorning By adding a converting constructor template in `tempClass`. I added that as an example and now added a little demo too.